# Why is the union of two closed intervals disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In Tao's "Analysis II", he provides the following example of a disconnected set:

> Consider the set $X := [1,2]\cup [3,4]$, with the usual metric. This set is disconnected because the sets $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are open relative to $X$.

I don't understand why the two intervals are open relative to $X$. In order for them to be open, don't we need an $r > 0$ such that the $B(x,r) \subseteq [1,2]$ for all $x \in [1,2]$? How does such an $r$ exist at the points $1$,$2$? And the same for the interval $[3,4]$.

Comment: A space is disjoint union of two of its open subsets if and only if it’s also the disjoint union of two of its closed subsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that they only need to be open *relative to $X$*.  That means that there only needs to be $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\cap X\subseteq [1,2]$  (or equivalently, the notation $B(x,r)$ should be interpreted with respect to the metric space $X$, not the metric space $\mathbb{R}$, so $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$).  So for $x=1$ or $x=2$ you could pick $r=1/2$, for instance.