# Why is $[1,2]$ relatively open in $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

From Tao, Analysis II.

> Consider the set $X := [1,2] \cup [3,4]$, with the usual metric. This set is disconnected because the sets $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are open relative to $X$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1915721/810368) starts from the same book section but I need more clarification. I will try to explain my guess of what's going on.

- A set $S$ is open iff it contains none of its boundary points.
- A boundary point is a point that is not an interior point or an exterior point.
- An interior point is a point where an open ball can be drawn around the point which is a subset of $S$.
- An exterior point is a point where an open ball can be drawn around the point which is disjoint from $S$.

For example, $1.5$ is an interior point of $[1,2]$ because letting $r=.1$, $(1.4,1.6) \cap X = (1.4,1.6) \subset [1,2]$.

Likewise, 1.0 is an interior point of $[1,2]$ because letting $r=.1$, $(0.9,1.1) \cap X = (1.0,1.1) \subset [1,2]$.

On the other hand, 3.5 is an exterior point because letting $r=.1$, $(3.4,3.6) \cap X = \emptyset$ .

All points in $X$ are either interior or exterior; X has no boundary points of $[1,2]$. So all of $[1,2]$'s boundary points are outside $[1,2]$, a vacuous truth since there are no such points. So $[1,2]$ is relatively open in $X$.

Is that what's happening, or is it something else?

Comment: It is quite simply because its complement in $X$, which is $[3,4]$, is closed in $X$.

Comment: Man I don't know.  Hardly anybody ever uses notions of boundary, exterior, or interior points because it's just needlessly complicated.  You can use equivalent definitions of open set which make the proof trivial.

Comment: Have it simple. $[1,2]=X\cap(0,\frac52)$ that is why $[1,2]$ is open in $X$.

Comment: The approach from @A.Sharma is probably the easiest to apprehend and use. It relies on the fact that your space $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Since you are using the same metric, the topology of $X$ is the trace topology from $\mathbb{R}$. That means that a set $U\subseteq X$ is open __in $X$__ iff there exists some open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (open in $\mathbb{R}$!) such that $U = X\cap V$.

Comment: @A.Sharma Mathematical mistakes should not be corrected as an edit to the post. It is better to point them out in the comments. You can read the comments and answers on [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32110/someone-edited-my-answer-now-it-is-wrong) post to understand why I suggest this.

Comment: @Sahiba Arora you are right.

Comment: While proving $1$ is an interior point $(0.9,1.1)\cap X$ will be $[1,1.1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that there are no boundary points. In fact, every point is an interior point. Your argument that $3.5$ is an exterior point is incorrect because $(3.4,3.6)\cap X=(3.4,3.6).$

Although the approach by @A.Sharma in the comments is the simpler, think it is still instructive for you to be able to prove it in your way.

Let's show **every** point is an interior point. Suppose $x \in [1,2].$ Then $$\{y:|x-y|<1\}\cap X=[1,2) \text{ or }[1,2] \text{ or }(1,2].$$ In either case $\{y:|x-y|<1\}\cap X\subseteq X.$ Therefore every point of $[1,2]$ is an interior point and thus $[1,2]$ is open in $X.$

Similarly for $x \in [3,4],$ $$\{y:|x-y|<1\}\cap X=[3,4) \text{ or }[3,4] \text{ or }(3,4].$$ In either case $\{y:|x-y|<1\}\cap X\subseteq X.$ Therefore every point of $[3,4]$ is an interior point and thus $[3,4]$ is open in $X.$

Comment: Because $[1,2]$ has no boundary points in $X$ it is also relatively closed in $X$?

Comment: @andi Yes because a set is closed if it contains all its boundary points.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you.